# Why does installing boto3 break my installation of awscli?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, boto3

I am trying to install boto3 so I can use it in my python script that I want to run on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04. Anyway I install boto3 it breaks my installation of awscli on the non root user. I install awscli using apt get with `sudo apt-get install awscli`. After I install it, it works on both the root user and the ubuntu user.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-12-10-8:~$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.14.65 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-143-generic botocore/1.9.18
ubuntu@ip-10-12-10-8:~$ sudo aws --version
aws-cli/1.14.65 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-143-generic botocore/1.9.18
```

I have also tried installing awscli like AWS suggests with `sudo pip install awscli --upgrade --user`. Also if it means anything pip only runs as the root user maybe thats installed wrong.

Here is the output when I install boto3 with pip.

But anytime I install boto3 with pip it breaks it for the ubuntu user. I have tried to install boto3 and then install awscli in many different ways and nothing works. Here are the ways I have tried.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-12-10-8:~$ sudo pip install boto3
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting boto3
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:339: 
SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:137: 
  InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading boto3-1.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (128kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 6.9MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 in 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from boto3)
Collecting botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.4 (from boto3)
  Downloading botocore-1.10.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.2MB 328kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<2.7.0,>=2.1 in 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.4->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.4->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil<2.7.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.4->boto3)
Installing collected packages: botocore, boto3
  Found existing installation: botocore 1.9.18
    Uninstalling botocore-1.9.18:
      Successfully uninstalled botocore-1.9.18
Successfully installed boto3-1.7.4 botocore-1.10.4
```

And then this is the result. I need aws tool to work on both users like it does before the boto3 install.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-12-10-8:~$ aws --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
ImportError: No module named botocore.session
ubuntu@ip-10-12-10-8:~$ sudo aws --version
aws-cli/1.14.65 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-143-generic botocore/1.10.
```

What is going on? I have been at this forever.

Comment: What if you install awscli again?

Comment: Still does not work. Gives same error.

Comment: try this one: `sudo pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade`

Comment: I have tried this command out of a different SO post. It results in aws working only on the sudo user as well.

Comment: How about `sudo -H pip`. It installs for all users.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use, it will also install the awscli and the aws-shell which has autocomplete and stuff.

```
$ sudo pip install aws-shell --upgrade --ignore-installed six
```

Let me know if this fixes boto3 and awscli.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The response from the `awscli` maintainers is "don't use anything but `pip` to install `awscli`". https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2353#issuecomment-270492205

Per a couple of the comments to use `sudo` for `pip install`. This will work, but as mentioned `sudo -H pip install somepackage` or maybe better `sudo -H -E pip install somepackage` should get it installed and available system wide. Another option would be to train your users to use `pip install --user awscli` so only those users that need to run it have it available and malicious scripts/users can't access things using the IAM role of the instance.

If it still isn't working with the above it may be this corner case bug where if `/tmp` is mounted with `noexec` the post install doesn't correctly mark the `aws` binary with `+x` permissions. You can try running `python3 /usr/bin/aws` or `python /usr/bin/aws` (it may also be in /usr/local/bin/aws) and see if that returns the expected output of the `aws` command.

Another alternative as mentioned in another answer is to install it into a virtual environment, and this is a pretty good way to isolate things but can be tricky to deal with making it available system-wide with the right permissions if you aren't familiar with virtual environments.

Answer (score -2):

If you never use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/), do it now.

Or you can use [conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html), yet another python virtual environment.

It will fix your "problem".

It is a by design "problem".  Nevertheless, even not using AWSCLI, one must always learn to setup python virtualenv for their python application, even there is only one project.